# Intermittent behavior of login to memberpage, session/redirect fails in wordpress / PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, session, redirect

I have done a memberpage using an external interface to check if the user is allowed to login to the memberpage. The code looks like this

```
<?php
require (__DIR__ .'/Permission/checkUser.php');




if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  session_start();


 $errors = array();


  if (empty ($_POST ['user']) ||
      empty ($_POST ['password'])) {

    $errors[] = 'Användarnamn och passord får inte vara tomt';

  }

  $checkuser = new checkUser();
  if ($checkuser->checkUser($_POST ['user'], $_POST ['password']) == false){
    $errors[] = 'Kontrollera user och lösenord';
  }


  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $_SESSION['userid'] = md5(microtime());
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();

    wp_redirect( get_permalink( 18341 ) );
    die;

  }

}

?>
```

If a succesful result from the SOAP call is returned the user are redirected to memberpage. The code fore memberpage are as following

```
<?php



 require_once 'sessioncheck.php';
 get_header();
 $container = get_theme_mod( 'understrap_container_type' );

?>
```

After performing the check the HTML are presenting the memberpage content.

The sessioncheck.php has the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
  //session does not exist send back to loginpage
  header('Location: memberLogin');
}

if (isset($_SESSION['start']) && (time() - $_SESSION['start'] > 1800)) {
    // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
    header('Location: memberLogin');
}


?>
```

It is suppose to unset and destroy the session if 30 minutes has passed.

My problem is that sometimes, often after a session has expired the redirect in the first code does not work. Its actually not even trying to load the memberpage. I first thought I had some problems with the session variables but now I think there might be some garbage from the session that causes this problem. It semse to be intermittent but I have asked other to test the page (using the right cred) and they always semse to be able to login on there first attempt to fail later on.

What am I doing wrong? Using PHP 7.4 with the latest WP core.

EDIT:

Added the following code to clean up sessions and cookie

```
$_SESSION = array();

    

  if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
    $params["path"], $params["domain"],
    $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
  }

  // Finally, destroy the session.
  session_destroy();
```

Now everything works fine when I am logged in as an adminuser in wordpress. However, as soon as I log out it stops working. However, the session is saved and if I log in again at WP, then I am able to enter the memberpage without doing the login procedure. I updated the page in WP (memberpage) and it worked again. This is all confusing me right now... :(

Answer (score 0):

Solved, clearing Session cookie and purged cache solved the issue. Needed exclude memberpage from cache. Didnt work with LiteSpeed cache